# Is there a "scanning" beam sensor?

Tags: sensor

As I understand it, photo beam sensors (and perhaps other emission types) work like this...

[image]

it occurred to me, it would be great if there was a "scanning" such sensor...

[image]

So, it would rotate or swing, at many Hz, over perhaps 90 degrees.  (It could rotate mechanically just like an airport radar or I guess a bar-code scanner, or perhaps "rotate" in some solid state manner.)

When an object cuts the beam, in fact it could tell you **the angular bearing**.

(Of course, if you put two or three of them over an opening, you could calculate a position in 2D nicely.)

In fact, does this technology exist .. is there such a photoelectric beam sensor -like device, which indeed will give you an "angular bearing"?

I've spent considerable time searching but not been able to discombobulate.

(I was astounded to learn there is a lidar-like [thing](http://www.pepperl-fuchs.com/global/en/24407.htm) that actually measures distance via time of flight, but that's sort of a further (amazing) complication, not really what I'm wondering about.)  Thx, experts

PS I have no interest at all in model or manufacturer recommendations. I just want to know if such a thing exists. (For all I know, it's completely commonplace .. or it may be obviously "ridiculously impossible" to experts.  Cheers)

Comment: Why does lidar not satisfy this?

Comment: You could certainly build one - by taking a standard lidar and adding a mirror on a stepper, or (at slower speeds) mounting it on a hobby servo.

Comment: Well, I'm feeling a bit discombobulated by this question if that's any help.

Comment: Is that like asking why a nuclear power plant doesn't satisfy the need for a 9V battery?  :) I only want, or wonder if exists, a spinning 20 dollar photoelectric sensor, which would give the "angular bearing".  Quite different from (incredibly) measuring distance with lidar at a very high price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main obstacle to this is that a traditional beam break has a point source and a point sensor. The system as you described would have to have a linear sensor in order to tell you where the break was, which would be more expensive.

It's certainly not impossible. Related work includes "structured light" (combining a scanning or otherwise patterned laser with a camera to give a 3D image), or the [Flat Frog](http://www.flatfrog.com/products) system for very large touchscreens. That has a large number of LEDs and photodiodes around the edge and detects fingers by successively illuminating from different angles and looking for the shadow.

Comment: Hi PJC .. hmm, you'd simply have a reflector on the "right" in the diagram.  TBC we actually MADE! one, with two dollars worth of reflective tape, and I just rotated the sensor left and right with my hand (say every couple seconds).  The flat frog tip is a fantastic one, thank you.

Comment: So sorry I forgot to tick this .. someone should have messaged me!  thanks again for the great answer!